# Windows 10 not using available CPU power?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10

Recently i upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and noticed a very bizarre system behaviour.

When monitoring task manager for some hours i can confirm that the CPU usage NEVER goes more than about 40-45%. It's like something is preventing Windows to use all the CPU power available. My power plan is already on 'High performance'.

I did a test with a self-developed app that does a loop that should use 100% CPU and indeed, when i run this app on Windows 8.1, CPU freezes on 100%, but the same app on Windows 10 stays on 40-45%.

My machine is a Macbook Pro with 16GB RAM / Core i7, and i use Parallels to run Windows. I have both machines, the older Win 8.1 before the upgrade and the recently upgraded one ; so i can compare the same apps and can confirm everything on Win 8.1 runs faster then Win 10.

Any hints to release my Win 10 power ? ;)

Thanks

Comment: Dont suppose i could ask you to test it with Prime95 or intelburn  linpack or any of those cpu torture programs which you can select the number of threads and tell what happens to them? (just my own interest)  Since like vista they have progressivly tried to have the os discover locked and non reponding programs to keep infinate loops etc from killing the os, they put them back some.   I wonder if they adjusted that again.  What is the programming method of Loop you are using?

Comment: For that matter, what happens when you run two or more copies of your app simultaneously?  If you're comparing two different machines, maybe the old one can run only a single thread, and the new one can run two, and your app is single-threaded, so it can never saturate the CPU(s).

Comment: My app just has a loop that never ends, such like this : while true do begin end;  this should use a all cpu available and indeed, it would use in Windows 8.1. But not in Win 10, it seems somehow Win 10 is limiting the cpu usage. If i run 2 copies of this same app, each one will use about 25% of CPU. I'm very confused, but i'm sure for some reason Win 8.1 is faster.